# How can I protect white risers (and oak treads) when using a hand truck on stairs?

Tags: stairs, protection

After replacing the old carpeted stairs in our condo with oak treads and painted white risers, I now need to move a few large / heavy pieces of furniture from the first floor to the second, or vice versa.

I never worried about using my hand truck (a.k.a. "utility dolly") on the carpeted stairs, but I'm very reluctant to use it on these pristine new stairs for fear of scuffing the risers.

Is there a common method to protect painted risers (and/or oak treads) from damage when moving furniture with a utility dolly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running a hand truck as part of a specific project, tape rosin paper to the stairs, and be careful when going up and down.  You can buy this at a hardware stores.

This also works for floors, though masonite boards underneath work well.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably rent the neoprene mats that movers use from a local store.   But they can move around as you go up and down the stairs, so could be a potential trip hazard.  It's unlikely you could find any floor protection that would protect your floor from dropping or scraping furniture across your stairs.

Please bear in mind that hardwood stairs are very slippery.  We ended up putting little individual tread mats on the hardwood stairs, using double-sided tape.

Comment: Thanks. We did buy the tread mats, although I'm going to have to add some kind of adhesive to them, because we're always having to straighten them.

I checked the hand truck, and the wheel only contacts the riser on two of the steps (I'm guessing they are the steps that take up the remainder of the height). For those two, I just used painters tape and some heavy-duty packing paper.

Comment: Good luck Scott.